# telethon edit_admin not working when Im not owner of the channel

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Im using this code:

```
await client.edit_admin(chat,admin,
        post_messages=None,
        add_admins=False,
        change_info=True,
        delete_messages=True,
        edit_messages=True)
```

it just stopped working suddenly. now it works fine when I am owner of a channel. but dosen't work when Im an admin with full premissions. I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

The person must be administered by a robot otherwise they will not have access

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can only grant permissions you have yourself (so if you can't ban people, you can't make someone else admin to ban people).